# seasonal_order in statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX for daily data

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying to understand how to set `s` for the seasonal order in the context of [statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html). Per the documentation:

> s is an integer giving the periodicity (number of periods in season), often it is 4 for quarterly data or 12 for monthly data. Default is no seasonal effect.

I believe this implies that for daily data with a yearly trend, I should set `s` to 365. I've read the [source code](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py#L31) and [this](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411sdif.htm) and it seems to me like I'm correct and that `s` should be set to 365 for daily data with a yearly trend.

The part that have me uncertain are that (A) it takes forever to run a model with `s` set to 365 and (B) [this particular line](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py#L342) and [this particular line](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsm) in the source code. I just want to make certain that I am interpreting `s` correctly, and that it shouldn't be set to 12 for 12 months of daily data.